# Adding NSMutableArray to NSMutableDictionary and the arrays are null?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

I've got a simple object "post" that has two `NSMutableArrays` as properties.  One is for "image" objects and the other is for "video" objects.  At some point in the lifecycle of "post", I ask it for a dictionary representation of itself.

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [post getDictionary];

-(NSMutableDictionary *)getDictionary{

    NSMutableArray *imgDictArry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
    NSMutableArray *movDictArry = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:nil];

    for (int i = 0; i<self.images.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *imgDict = [[self.images objectAtIndex:i] getDictionary];
        [imgDictArry addObject:imgDict];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i<self.videos.count; i++) {
        NSMutableDictionary *movDict = [[self.videos objectAtIndex:i] getDictionary];
        [movDictArry addObject:movDict];
    }

    NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.friendsOnly], @"IsFriendsOnly", 
                                     self.message, @"Message",
                                     self.shortText, @"ShortText",
                                     self.authorId, @"AuthorId",
                                     self.recipientId, @"RecipientId",
                                     self.language, @"Language",
                                     self.lat, @"Lat",
                                     self.lng, @"Lng",
                                     imgDictArry, @"Images",
                                     movDictArry, @"Videos",
                                     nil];

    return postDict;
}
```

As you can see, the "image" and "video" objects have their own methods for describing themselves as `NSMutableDictionary` objects.

```
-(NSMutableDictionary *)getDictionary{
    return [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
            self.nativeURL, @"NativeURL",
            self.previewURL, @"PreviewURL",
            self.smallURL, @"SmallURL",
            self.thumbURL, @"ThumbURL",
            self.imageId, @"ImageId",
            self.width, @"Width",
            self.height, @"Height",
            nil];
}
```

I'm not getting any errors but my `imgDictArry` and `movDictArry` objects are turning out to be `NULL` after I've set them on the `postDict` object.  If I log them to the console just before this moment, I can see the dictionary data.  But the other classes requesting this object is getting null for those properties.

Comment: (Sidenote: it's poor style to preface a property's name with "get" in Objective-C. `dictionaryValue` and `dictionaryRepresentation` are better. Or even just `dictionary`.)

Comment: Also, methods generally shouldn't be declared as returning mutable objects, unless you specifically are exposing it to be mutated by the caller (as in NSMutableData's `mutableBytes`), and you should declare and use macros or global string variables instead of sprinkling copies of the same string literal all over your code.

Comment: Also, you can just say `[NSMutableArray array]` instead of using `arrayWithObjects:`, and you should use fast enumeration instead of looping over the arrays by index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps one of your functions such as `self.shortText` (or `self.lat`...) is returning `nil`, in which case `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys` isn't what you expect it to be: it's truncated to the first function that returns `nil`...

Comment: Also, all of the objects you pass to `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` must be *objects*; passing numeric values will either cause this problem (if 0) or almost-certainly crash (if not 0). You can even get both, if the value is smaller than a pointer (`dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:` will consume a pointer's worth no matter what, not realizing that you didn't pass one).

Comment: Yes, i think that's the most probable cause of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the postDict creation to this...

```
NSMutableDictionary *postDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSNumber numberWithBool:self.friendsOnly], @"IsFriendsOnly", 
                                     self.message, @"Message",
                                     self.shortText, @"ShortText",
                                     self.authorId, @"AuthorId",
                                     self.recipientId, @"RecipientId",
                                     self.language, @"Language",
                                     self.lat, @"Lat",
                                     self.lng, @"Lng",
                                     nil];

    [postDict setObject:imgDictArry forKey:@"Images"];
    [postDict setObject:movDictArry forKey:@"Videos"];
```

and it's fixed.  But I don't know why.

Comment: E-Madd: Read Zoran Simic's answer.